# If $0$ is in the multiplicative set then the fraction ring contains only one element

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Given a commutative ring with unity, $\mathcal R$, and a multiplicative set $S,$ to define the fraction ring $S^{-1}\mathcal R$ one defines an equivalence relation $(a,s)\sim (a^{\prime},s^{\prime}),$ where $ a,a^{\prime} \in \mathcal R$, and $s,s^{\prime} \in S$ if the following equation is satisfied: $$ k(as^{\prime}-sa^{\prime})=0, \text {for some} \,k \in S.$$

In the book that I am learning from, there is the statement: "If $0\in S,$ then the only element (which means equivalence class) of $S^{-1} \mathcal R$ is $0/1.$" It is this statement that I don't understand. If $0 \in S,$ then the above equation is satisfied for all pairs $(a,s), (a^{\prime},s^{\prime}).$ Two other things are also unclear to me:

- Is $k \in S$ in the above equation supposed to be unique for each such two pairs or equivalence class ?
- Must one assume that $\mathcal R$ is an integral domain ?

Thanks for your comment.

Comment: "the above equation is satisfied for all pairs $(a,s), (a^{\prime},s^{\prime}).$", that's the issue, all pairs are in relation with each other, so the quotient kills everything since there is only one equivalence class

Comment: If $\mathcal{R}$ is an integral domain and $0\not\in S$ you can use the simpler relation $(a,s)\sim (a^{\prime},s^{\prime})\iff as^\prime-sa^\prime=0$, but even easier in this case you can think about $S^{-1}\mathcal{R}$ as the smallest subring of $\operatorname{Frac}(\mathcal{R})$ containing $\mathcal{R}$ and $\{1/s\mid s\in S\}$

Comment: For each "$s$" in your display, which ones are the "$s,s' \in S$"s and which are the "$\text{for some } s \in S$"s?  Reusing letters for different purposes in the same sentence is likely to be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Note that two different variables have the same name $s$ in your definition of the fraction ring.

> If $0 \in S,$ then the above equation is satisfied for all pairs
>   $(a,s), (a^{\prime},s^{\prime}).$

- Yes, and that is why there is only one equivalence class.
- $\mathfrak{s}$ is not supposed to be unique (if $S$ contains some product $\mathfrak{ts}$, then $\mathfrak{ts}(as^{\prime}-sa^{\prime})=0$ as well.)
- There is a priori no reason to ask for $\mathcal R$ to be an integral domain, in fact otherwise the sentence "$ \mathfrak{s}(as^{\prime}-sa^{\prime})=0, \text {for some} \,\mathfrak{s} \in S$" would seem a bit silly.

Comment: @user249018 the only equivalence class is $(1,0)$, not $(0,1)$.